# ¿ Como añadir un nuevo tipo de letra a WordPress?

Tags: css, css3, wordpress, fuentes, font-faces

Quiero utilizar un tipo de letra en concreto en un sitio web.
No quiero utilizar ningún tipo de complemento, y la tipografía que quiero, no la encuentro gratuita para añadir medie¡ante enlace  por lo que he decidido con el método `@font-face`

1 - A el archivo styles.css le añado el siguiente código:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: university-roman;  
    src: url(https://mySitioWeb.com/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/fonts/university-roman.otf);
    font-weight: normal;  
}
```

2 - He creado la carpeta  `fonts` en la ruta siguiente de mis directorio:

```
wp-content/themes/mi-Tema/fonts/university-roman.otf
```

3 - He añadido el css correspondiente a el texto donde quiero añadir las nuevas fuentes:

```
.site-title-main { 
font-family: "university-roman", Arial, sans-serif; 
}
```

Pero el texto no muestra las fuentes de University.

¿ Que estoy haciendo mal ?

¿ Como puedo hacer que funciones los nuevos tipos de letras ?
Espero haber descrito el problema que no puedo solucionar.
Gracias

Comment: mira a ver si te sirve [esto](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-wordpress)

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte @chikebox , pero si usted se fija, lo que muestra su enlace, es lo que yo hice. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar a cargar las fuentes desde CDN,(Content Delivery Network - red de entrega de contenidos) esto puede funcionar.

Otra opción es subir tus fuentes a Firebase y llamarlas allí.

[Fuente de inspiración](https://es.quora.com/Alguien-sabe-de-un-servicio-de-CDN-para-CSS-JS-e-im%C3%A1genes-Quiero-subir-mis-archivos-CSS-y-JS-para-luego-usarlos-igual-que-Bootstrap-o-jQuery)

De cualquier modo, llamas a las fuentes con @font-face en tu archivo styles.css de la siguiente forma:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'University Roman Std';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('University Roman Std'), url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/s/39875/UniversityRomanStdRegular.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'University Roman Std';
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('University Roman Std'), url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/s/39875/UniversityRomanStdItalic.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'University Roman Std';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: local('University Roman Std'), url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/s/39875/UniversityRomanStdBold.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Y lo llamas desde el CSS personalizado:

```
.section-title-main {
        font-family: 'University Roman Std', sans-serif 
}
```

Espero esto sea de ayuda

Answer (score 3):

Fíjate que cuando defines el atributo `font-family` dentro de `@font-face` ese es el valor que tienes que usar cuando mencionas el nombre de fuente en el CSS.

O sea, en tu ejemplo, quedaría así:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: university-roman;  
    src: url(https://mySitioWeb.com/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/fonts/university-roman-otf);
    font-weight: normal;  
}

.site-title-main { 
    font-family: "university-roman", Arial, sans-serif; 
}
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte @HernanColiqueo , efectivamente no la estaba llamando, pero después de corregir, sigue sin funcionar. Editare la pregunta para que no haya más confusiones

Comment: Se me ocurre que el src no es correcto, ya que lo tienes en local... porque no apuntas a tu carpeta local?

Comment: si, podrías mostrar el código completo o usar rutas relativas? en el src fijate dice "university-roman-otf"

Comment: tambien fijate que en el src está definido como parametro y no como string, te diría lo encomilles

Comment: El código que muestro es el que utilizo @HernánColiqueo . No hice todo exactamente como lo muestro en la pregunta. 
Y todo el código esta como lo muestro, he probado a cambiar lo de las comillas, pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: has probado la url declarada en src en tu navegador?

Comment: 1) cuando tu aplicas la clase al elemento y pruebas la página en el navegador, usando la consola de devtools (o similar) compruebas que de hecho los cambios que realizaste se aplican verdad? me refiero a que el estilo está computado para ese elemento con los atributos que has especificado, verdad?
2) también hay que descartar que el cache, alguna solución de mejora de performance, no esté afectando tu visualizacion